# Ban command will not let me ban others

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am a higher rank then the person I am trying to ban, but the error "❌│ I couldn't kick this person, check if I'm higher than the person you are trying to ban!" If someone could fix and help me that would be great, thanks!

**Code -**

```js
if (
 msg.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') ||
 msg.member.displayName === 'PixelIGPM8' ||
 msg.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')
) {
 let member = msg.mentions.members.first();
 // prevents from not mentionning
 if (!member)
  return msg.channel.send(`│ Imagine not mentioning someone to kick...`);
 // If the code continues, then there is a mention
 try {
  user.kick();
  msg.channel.send(`│ Kicked! @${member.user.displayName}!`);
 } catch (err) {
  msg.channel.send(
   '❌│ I couldnt kick this person, check if im higher than the person you are trying to ban!'
  );
 }
} else msg.channel.send('❌│lol noob you dont have permission to do this.');
```

Comment: The bot needs to be higher rank, not you

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă It is.

Comment: It should be `member.kick()`

Comment: I would highly recommend to remove this piece of code: `msg.member.displayName === "PixelIGPM8"` simply that if I change my nickname in the server to `PixelIGPM8`, I can use this command since you are using pipelines in your if statement (`if/or`).

Comment: The `ADMINISTRATOR` flag is redundant in your code as well, since roles with administrator rights already have `KICK_MEMBERS` permissions included.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to do the Role's ID, not name in if `(msg.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')`

Answer (score -3):

`user.kick()` is where your code is getting caught up because you should just use `member.kick()` as it is the member object that has the kick method. You can read more about it [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kick)

Comment: let member = msg.mentions.members.first();

Comment: You're using `user.kick()` instead of `member.user.kick()`.

Comment: `member.user.kick()` wouldn't work either as `user` is a `User` object, not a `GuildMember`